# Why Angular form control validator only exist in console log, if there empty string as another parmeter?

Tags: json, angular, mongodb

I am trying to console log out the angular form control validator itself and try to JSON.stringfy it to store to MongoDB.

I try following statement.

```
let a = new formControl ([Validators.required]) ;
```

result:

```
{defaultValue:null, .... validator:null }
```

I try again with a modified statement.

```
let a = new formControl ('',[Validators.required]) ;
```

result:

```
{defaultValue:null, .... validator:ƒ (control)}
```

Why it is literally null and somehow if I add an empty string it acknowledge Validators.required exist?

Comment: Because the first argument of `FormControl` is used to set the value. For the first code, you are setting the form control with value: `[Validators.required]`. You may read the [constructors](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor) for more info.

Comment: I asked chatgpt it said its fine, chatgpt trick me again. Human wins again.

Comment: Haha, would say never trust anyone/bot until you have tested the code and it works. :D